# Follow DRY principles while writing jest mocks in test cases - React and Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, dry

I'm new to testing and I wanted to follow the DRY principle for my unit test cases. In my test cases, I'm mocking react-redux's useSelector and useDispatch and currently writing the same mock in all the tests wherever react-redux is used. Below is one of my test case.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import LayoutComponent from './LayoutComponent';


const mockDispatch = jest.fn();
jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-redux'),
    useSelector: jest.fn(),
    useDispatch: () => mockDispatch
}));

const setup = () => {
    return shallow(<LayoutComponent />)
}

const mockState = (state) => {
    return useSelector.mockImplementationOnce(callback => {
        return callback(state);
    })
}

jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual("react-router-dom"),
    useLocation: () => ({
        pathname: "localhost:3000/"
    })
}));

describe('LayoutComponent', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    })
    test('Calls getUserInfo on mount', () => {
        setup();
        expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(Function));
expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });

});
```

Instead of writing this mock in all the test files, I want to keep react-redux mock separate so that I can import it in all the files wherever these are used and no need to write them again and again.

Can anyone please help me with this. Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

I have created a directory called `__mocks__` right beside `node_modules` folder and inside `__mocks__` folder I've created `react-redux.js` file. Inside the file I've the below mock functions.

```
const mockDispatch = jest.fn()

module.exports = {
    ...jest.requireActual('react-redux'),
    __esModule: true,
    useSelector: jest.fn(),
    useDispatch: () => mockDispatch,
    mockDispath,
};
```

Below is the test

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import ResolutionCount from '../ResolutionCount';
import { mockDispatch, mockState } from 'react-redux';

const setup = props => {
    return shallow(<ResolutionCount componentUsedIn={props} />)
}

describe("ResolutionCount component", () => {
    test("testing component with prop value", () => {
        mockState({
            userInfoReducer: {
                userInfo: [
                    {
                        user_id: 'some id',
                        user_name: 'some name',
                        user_email: 'someemail@email.com',
                        user_pic: null,
                        is_admin: true,
                        is_super_user: false,
                    },
                ]
            }
        });

        setup("my resolutions");

        expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            type: "SET_RESOLUTION_STATUS_COUNT_BAR_CHART_FETCHING_DATA",
            payload: true,
        });

    })
})
```

so now when I'm running the test I'm getting the error saying that

```
TypeError: (0 , _reactRedux.mockState) is not a function
 describe("ResolutionCount component", () => {
      11 |     test("testing component with prop value", () => {
    > 12 |         mockState({
         |         ^
      13 |             userInfoReducer: {
      14 |                 userInfo: [
      15 |                     {
```

[image: Error]
[image: Folder structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reusable mocks from `__mocks__` directory is a way that Jest provides for this.

In case a spy needs to be accessed directly in order to modify the implementation or assert it, it can be added to module exports, name collisions with existing exports have to be avoided with `mock` prefix or else.

*<root>/__mocks__/react-redux.js*

```
const mockDispatch = jest.fn();

module.exports = {
    ...jest.requireActual('react-redux'),
    __esModule: true,
    useSelector: jest.fn(),
    useDispatch: jest.fn(() => mockDispatch),
    mockDispatch
};
```

The mock is supposed to be automatically applied on import. Then `mockDispatch` can be imported in tests as usual:

```
import { mockDispatch } from 'react-redux';
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Jest is very new to me! In my react project where do I need to create the __mock__ folder? I've created it in the src/ directory. and also can you please tell me how can I access this in the test cases. Because I've one more test function mockState which will mock the useSelector. Please help

Comment: It needs to be in the same place as node_modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules . You need to access it as any other export, `import { mockDispatch } from 'react-redux'`.

Comment: so in that case, I need to re create the files again whenever I delete node_modules folder? Also we won't be pushing the node_modules directory to the github in that case it will be missed out right?

Comment: It should be located at the same level as node_modules, not inside of it.

Comment: I'm getting an error. I've updated the procedures that I've followed and what error I'm currently getting. Please help

Comment: The error means that the mock is not picked up. It's `__mocks__`, not `__mock__`. Please, refer to the documentation linked above, it's very specific about this feature.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221812/discussion-between-aashay-amballi-and-estus-flask).

Comment: I went through the docs couple of times but I was not able to find out the error :(
I have created `__mocks__` folder right beside node_modules and in my component I'm trying to import for ex `import {mockStore} from 'react-redux'` and when I'm trying to access mockStore I'm getting the error `TypeError: (0 , _reactRedux.mockState) is not a function`. Really I'm not understanding. Please help, I'm stuck with this error for more than 5 hours. This could be a simple issue but not able to figure it out

Comment: I have updated the folder structure and error image in the question. Please have a look :(

Comment: This is specific to your setup. It seems you use create-react-app project, `__mocks__` likely should be located in src instead of root directory. See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7539 .

Comment: Thank you for your response, now I'm getting a different error `ReferenceError: mockDispath is not defined`. Is this because of some hoisting?

Comment: There was a typo in code. It should be `mockDispatch`, not `mockDispath`.

Comment: Thank you so much Estus Flask. This whole time I was trying to fix the mockDispatch typo in the root directory `__mocks__` file. Later I realized I had to fix it in the `src/__mocks__`. Fixed the typo and it actually worked. I really can't thank you enough! and I really am grateful to you for helping me with this.